# use a php variable in diffrent pages

Tags: php

I have two pages of php on the same folder , Im wondering what can I do to use that variable in another page like page2.php
page1.php

```
$variable = "Variable";
```

page2.php

```
//get $variable value from page1.php here
```

Any suggestions? Thank You

Comment: Would it be a constant variable or a variable you would manipulate?

Comment: @Philibobby - "constant variable" = oxymoron

Comment: @j08691 Ouch you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Sessions`.

On `page1.php`:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['var1'] = 'some text';
```

On `Page2.php`:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){ 
    session_start();
}
echo $_SESSION['var1'];
```

You will get `some test` as output.

Comment: this worked great! Thanks a lot , I wasn't using $_SESSION thats why it wasn't working

Answer (score 3):

Use [session variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).

Just write `session_start()` at the beginning of files to start a session and assign the session variables.

eg:

**File-1**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['var'] = "var";
```

**File-2**

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['var']))
   echo $_SESSION['var'];  // will print "var"
```

You can use this throughout till the session destroyed. To destroy the session (may be on logout)-

```
if(isset($_SESSION['var']))
   unset($_SESSION['var']);
```

To completely destroy the session-
    session_destroy();

Answer (score 2):

Or you can try constants like so:

constants.php

```
<?php
    define("VARIABLE_1", "Hotdog");
?>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
    include_once("constants.php");
    echo VARIABLE_1;
    // output == Hotdog
?>
```

Just include the constants php script in the pages you want to use the variables in.

Answer (score 1):

Check [PHP Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php):

page1.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['variable'] = "Variable";
```

page2.php

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['variable']
```

Comment: 1 minute after this one yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can `require_once("page2.php")` in `page1.php`

That will allow you to use variables in page 2 across page 1.

Alternatively, you can also use sessions.

`session_start()` starts a new session or resumes an existing session. Include this on the first line of both pages.

Session parameters are set using `$_SESSION["parameter-name"] = "something"`;

You can use the variables anywhere in the script.

To terminate sessions, use `session_destroy()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) to achieve this , also you should know about [QueryStrings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

For example:

Navigate to another page say `"location2.php?Variable=123"` here ?Variable is your var and 123 is value.

And on **location2.php** you can get this by simply `$_GET["Variable"];`

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in many ways. You can use [php session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php), [you can include](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) a file where you create that variable, or you can [define it as a consant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php).

All of that depends how complex is that problem and which suits you best in this case.